# Elasticsearch query_string wildcard syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

Apparently I can query ES with the following wildcard `query_string`:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*:sw?ft"
    }
  }
}'
```

Does this query against `_all` field ? which makes it equivalent to:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field" : "_all"
      "query": "sw?ft"
    }
  }
}'
```

what if `_all` is disabled in indexing? I couldn't find the documentation for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with the searching command set to `*:sw?ft` will be transformed to something like the following (assuming your `my-index` index has a single `my_field` field, for example):

```
(_field_names:sw?ft | _all:sw?ft | _index:sw?ft | _parent:sw?ft | _uid:sw?ft | _type:sw?ft | _routing:sw?ft | _version:sw?ft | _timestamp:sw?ft | _source:sw?ft | _size:sw?ft | my_field:sw?ft | _id:sw?ft | _ttl:sw?ft | _boost:sw?ft)
```

So, the wildcard before `:` will be expanded to all the fields in the index, not only your own defined fields. Be very careful with wildcards in `query_string`, they can affect in a bad way the performance of the cluster.

So, to answer your question, `*` will be expanded to **all** the fields of the index, including `_all`. If you would have used just `sw?ft` as searching string then this, by default, would have been used `_all`.

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic answer! I wonder where do you find all these details?

Comment: These details can be found using the [validate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_validating_queries.html#_understanding_queries) ;-). It's really useful, especially with `query_string`.

Comment: ahaa! it will become my new friend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's documentation for query_string query:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

And it has answers to both of your questions:

> When not explicitly specifying the field to search on in the query
>   string syntax, the `index.query.default_field` will be used to derive
>   which field to search on. It defaults to `_all` field.
>
> So, if `_all` field is disabled, it might make sense to change it to
>   set a different default field.

Comment: I am confused about the syntax of "*:sw?ft", I know i can use an individual field in place of the star, but does the star searches _all or each indexed field? If the star searches _all, AFAIK, _all is not lowercase, but query_string wildcard is, so it doesn't seems to make sense. Thank you for your reply.